# CentOS: What does the mount-Command and why is it necessary before setfacl

Tags: centos, mount, access-control-list

I need to use the setfacl-command for the first time. On centos.org they say, that you first need to mount the file (http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-acls.html).
What does the mount-command actually do, and why do I need to do this before I like to manage file-permissions with setfacl.

Answer (score 0):

Access Control Lists will work only on those mounted partitions which are mounted with 'acl' options.

In order to view current mount options set for the partitions, give the command

```
mount -l
```